# Java TimeZone head scratching

Tags: java, timezone

I would like to save some user timezone in a Daylight saving proof format.
My goal is to get the correct GMT offset whenever the code gets executed.
In order to figure out my best option, I wrote the following:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add( "EST");
list.add( "EDT");
list.add( "America/New_York");
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
for( String tzID: list) {
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone( tzID);
    System.out.println( tzID + " now=" + tz.getOffset( now) / 3600000 + " / +182=" + tz.getOffset( now + ( 182 * 86400000)) / 3600000);
}
```

For short, give me the offset now and in 182 days
Executed September 3rd, the output is

```
EST now=-5 / +182=-5
EDT now=0 / +182=0
America/New_York now=-4 / +182=-4
```

This is unexpected for several reasons
1) Why is America/New_York not giving -4/-5 ?, Isn't it supposed to be date sensitive?
2) Why does EDT == UTC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem you have is that 182 * 86400000 overflows. If you use

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
for( String tzID: "EST,EDT,America/New_York".split(",")) {
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone( tzID);
    System.out.println( tz.getDisplayName() + " now=" + tz.getOffset( now) / 36e5 
                     + " / +182=" + tz.getOffset( now + 182 * 86400000L) / 36e5);
}
```

prints

```
Eastern Standard Time now=-5.0 / +182=-5.0
Greenwich Mean Time now=0.0 / +182=0.0
Eastern Standard Time now=-4.0 / +182=-5.0
```

If you look at the javadoc and source for getTimeZone you can see

```
 * @return the specified <code>TimeZone</code>, or the GMT zone if the given ID
 * cannot be understood.

public static synchronized TimeZone getTimeZone(String ID) {
return getTimeZone(ID, true);
}

private static TimeZone getTimeZone(String ID, boolean fallback) {
TimeZone tz = ZoneInfo.getTimeZone(ID);
if (tz == null) {
    tz = parseCustomTimeZone(ID);
    if (tz == null && fallback) {
    tz = new ZoneInfo(GMT_ID, 0);
    }
}
return tz;
}
```

In short, EDT is not recognised so it becomes GMT.

Comment: That's the part were you feel alone for asking a dumb question ... thanks  :)

Comment: Its a pretty common question (re overflows). That's a not a dumb question, try `how do i go` in google and see what it suggests for a dumb question :D

Answer (score 5):

### java.time

The question and the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12248824/10819573) use the `java.util` date-time API which was the right thing to do in 2012. In March 2014, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) was released as part of the **Java 8 standard library** which supplanted the legacy date-time API and since then it is strongly recommended to switch to `java.time`, the modern date-time API.

### Solution using `java.time`

You can use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) which automatically adjusts the time zone offset for a given `ZoneId`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
        ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(zone);
        ZonedDateTime after182Days = now.plusDays(182);
        System.out.println(zone + " now=" + now.getOffset() + " / +182=" + after182Days.getOffset());
    }
}
```

**Output as of now**:

```
America/New_York now=-05:00 / +182=-04:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/pRHT1b)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Do not use three-letter timezone ID**: Note from the Java 7 `Timezone` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html):

> #### Three-letter time zone IDs
>
> For compatibility with JDK 1.1.x, some other three-letter time zone IDs (such as "PST", "CTT", "AST") are
> also supported. However, **their use is deprecated** because the same
> abbreviation is often used for multiple time zones (for example, "CST"
> could be U.S. "Central Standard Time" and "China Standard Time"), and
> the Java platform can then only recognize one of them.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is the problem:

```
now + ( 182 * 86400000)
```

The parenthesized arithmetic expression overflows 32 bits. You probably want:

```
now + ( 182 * 86400000L)
```

However, that still assumes that any daylight saving time will be applied for roughly six months, which is certainly not the case in the real world. For example, looking at the [Sao Paolo time zone](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=233), it switches in October and February - so if you ran your code in September, you'd end up seeing -3 / -3. Even for time zones where DST switches on/off roughly every six months, you're very likely to find 182 consecutive days each year without a switchover (almost by definition, given that that's slightly less than half a year).

It's not clear *exactly* what you're trying to do, but I suspect you should really just be saving the time zone ID, e.g. "America/New_York". Almost anything else is asking for trouble.